# Google Chrome Developer tools not showing inspected elements styles?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

I am using the google chrome developer tools for testing my website;

It is working fine for some elements, however for others it is showing the selector but showing it as having no styles; The element does have styles, and the styles are applied to the element. but the inspector shows no styles.

If I click the link to the css file line for that inspector I can see the styles there.

I saw a google group topic that stated that [removing any empty `url()` declarations](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/Z_TLvpOXrMg) fixed the bug. however I have no empty `url()` declarations.

I also found [this bug which is somewhat similar](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=136648); but not exactly the same. one thing I did notice is that both the usecase this bug provided and my setup are using twitter-bootstrap. I am using the .less version of bootstrap which includes bootstrap into the single css file as a copy > paste method, so my css file has **3740 lines**. could this be part of the issue?

The elements are not deep nested (`body > div#container > inspected element`).
There are not an excessive amount of styles applied to the elements (<= 10).

---

[Click to enlarge[image: Dev Tools Example]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6lEM.png)

Comment: Do the values show up under 'computed style'?

Comment: Yes, the styles show up under 'computed styles'

Comment: Maybe try running your css files through the validator to see if there are any errors which may be causing this to happen similar to the empty URL one you mentioned reading about? http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so I also found [this bug aswell](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=136901) which looks like it has a closer match to the bug.
It states that

> DevTools break when an unrecognised pseudo-class is present in CSS

which twitter-bootstrap does! so it looks like the dev tools are broken if you are using twitter bootstrap (or anything that tries to use vendor-specific pseudo classes). afaik the only way to solve this is to wait for this bug to be solved by the developers.

If someone can post a fix for this I will accept their answer!

Comment: Hi, I'm the guy who raised the first bug you linked. I'm pretty certain both it and the other bug are actually describing the same underlying issue, which is caused by Chrome choking on some aspect(s) of the standard bootstrap.css. My bug has been tagged as priority one, for inclusion in milestone 22 (the current dev milestone), so hopefully it won't take take long to be fixed. In the meantime, it's possible to use Firefox and Firebug to debug your CSS instead.

Comment: I've just reverted back to the stable channel for now, It would be highly appreciated if you could comment here when this is fixed.

Comment: It's fixed in today's dev channel release.

Comment: Yep, fixed too with the release 22.0.1221.0 dev.

Comment: For those who have the similiar problem which's not related to `twitter-bootstrap`, I suggest you to check the javascript files, especially modifying css rules. For example, I used `frefix-free.js` to facilitate vendor prefixes and this script changes all my css files. Therefore chrome thinks all the css rules are given by the html/php file you're viewing.