# Chrome Devtools go to css line not working

Tags: css, google-chrome, less, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using chrome devtools while working on a project and for some reason for this specific site that I am working on with a team ... the "Go to CSS line" has disappeard ... I am able to edit the css in the inspect element view but I cannot go to it's source to edit in like textedit view.

The css file is linked through a bundler and I tried taking it out of that bundler but with no success.

I ask my dev team but they are telling me they didn't do anything differently.

Comment: See this, maybe it could help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520563/google-chrome-developer-tools-not-showing-inspected-elements-styles

Comment: ok Fixed... The developers I am working with added prefixfree.min.js ... prefixfree lets you use only unprefixed CSS properties everywhere. but it was breaking my devtools and writing all css in-page instead of using it as an external file. Anyway .. hope this helps anyone that might come across this.